# Set permanent environment variable for all shells

Tags: bash, zsh, environment-variables, path, fish

I want to set the root level environment variable that comes from `sh(1)` so that it is shared across all shells: `sh`, `bash`, `zsh`, and `fish`.

I can see in `/etc/profile` there's a command `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s` which prints default values of `PATH` but it also has custom values set by other tools like `gcloud`, `mono`. How do those do this? I want to share my custom values as well.

I'm not going to add them to `/etc/profile` because that can be changed due to an update and I don't see `gcloud/mono/conda` specify their paths there. So what is the correct solution?

Any tips for keep all shells in sync would be very helpful.

I'm on macOS Catalina: 10.15.5 (19F101)

Comment: What OS? If Linux, what distro?

Comment: @ilkkachu added os. it is macOS.

Comment: fish does not have the same syntax as bash/zsh for setting variables, so your goal is impossible. You must have a separate config file for fish.

Comment: @glennjackman I know that, but PATH is variable and fish does inherit default values... so IDK how but it is possible.

Comment: @glennjackman environment variables get inherited to child processes...

Comment: For Linuxes, one answer could be `pam_env` and `/etc/environment`, but I have no idea how the similar stuff works on macOS.

Comment: Obviously fish inherits environment variables, but fish is my login shell so I'm not inheriting any bash/zsh PATH settings.

Comment: For MacOS, if you're interested in PATH/MANPATH only, check out `man path_helper` -- then look in /etc/paths, /etc/manpaths, /etc/paths.d/, /etc/manpaths.d/

Comment: I'm not going to start testing this extensively (changing my shell and logging on/off), but see [Environment variables in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/603785/6372809) and [How to set system-wide environment variables on OS X Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/107787/344368).

Comment: Possibly useful - as a starting point - on Ask Different: [Defining environment variables with launchd/launchctl](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/64916). Though I didn't see any mention to macOS 10.15, I couldn't tell if the linked solution are going to work in your case.

Comment: As at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/599443/5132 , this question is based upon a lot of confusion.  That's nowhere near "all shells".  `sh` is not some common base for all shells.  And the idea of a `sh` "root level" is confused about how login works and how processes inherit environment variables.

Comment: Are you trying to set $PATH specifically, or a different variable?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish It is for `PATH` and other things like shared config vars e.g. keys for accounts, projects variables which are used when running, special vars e.g. `EDITOR` or `DIFF_TOOL` or `PAGER` etc.